# How get to img element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when user clicked on `.fa-search-plus` an alert shows the src of the `.img-reponsive`

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-push-4 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="grid">
         <figure class="effect-hera">
            <img  class="img-responsive second"src="images/book4.png" data-   toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                               <figcaption>
                                <p>
                                     <a href="imageideas.org/pdf/4.pdf"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
                                     <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                                </p>
                           </figcaption>
                           </figure>
                       </div>
                  </div>

<script>
$(".fa-search-plus").click(function(){
         alert  ($(this).parent().parent().find('.img-responsive').attr('src'));
        })
</script>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code, all there is here is HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .closest() method of jQuery

```
    $(".fa-search-plus").click(function(){
        alert  ($(this).closest('.effect-hera').find('.img-responsive').attr('src'));
        });
```

or you can use parents() also

```
 $(".fa-search-plus").click(function(){
        alert  ($(this).parents('.effect-hera').find('.img-responsive').attr('src'));
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this code may be helpful for you:

```
var someimage = document.getElementById('this_one');
var myimg = someimage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var mysrc = myimg.src;
```